# How to handle concurrent bids in an online auction?

Tags: concurrency, queue

I wanted to how the system handles the concurrent bids. There is a possibility that two bidders might bid the same amount at the same time even going down to the milliseconds (considering a large number of users are bidding for the item). In that case, how will the system manage the bid?

For example;
A pendant is placed for a bid let's suppose. The current bid is $ 3.75. Now the next bidder must place a bid of $4 or more. Now, two bidders (multiple bidders) bid $4 at the same time, since they are seeing the current bid of $3.75. Multiple bidders bid the same amount at the same time. How will the system now handle the bid? If any one of them had placed the bid a bit earlier, then automatically the next bidder had to bid a little more than the previous bidder. But in this case, both bidders happened to bid the same amount at the same time for the same item.

Whose bid is considered to be the current bid?

Comment: Hey @guru-dev have you come up with any solution your self? I have the sam e question bothering me :).

Comment: You can make the rules in this scenario whatever you want, either you honor the earliest bid or the later one, down to the millisecond, assuming both are accepted.  this depends on your logic. if you process them serially (queue or db transaction that locks the bids table for that auction) then you would just reject the duplicate bid as at least one of them would of already been processed and the user has to re-bid.    if this is at the last few seconds of an auction the normal practice is to auto-extend the auction time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the least thing you could probably comes with is DB Transaction (which probably going to slow down your users experience) but, I think its a worth shot to try using Redis in this case!

Since Redis is single threaded.

And I also think you could probably make use of the `INCR` functionality of it since its the best way IMHO.

---

### Note:

I believe Redis also have been supporting Transaction since version 6 (CMIIW), but please be aware that Redis's Transaction doesn't support **rollback**.

Read more about Redis [Transaction](https://redis.io/docs/manual/transactions/) and [INCR](https://redis.io/commands/incr/).